# Call function with "this"

Tags: javascript

I have an onclick handler for an <a> element (actually, it's a jQuery-created handler, but that's not important).  It looks like this:

```
function handleOnClick() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        return handleOnClickConfirmed();
    }
    return false;
}
```

From this function, the **this** object is accessable as the <a> element clicked.  However, handleOnClickConfirmed's **this** is a Window element!  I want handleOnClickConfirmed to have the same **this** as handleOnClick does.  How would I do this?

(I know I can pass **this** as an argument to handleOnClickConfirmed, but some of my code already uses handleOnClickConfirmed and I don't want to have to rewrite those calls.  Besides, I think using **this** looks cleaner.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following ought to do it:

```
function handleOnClick() {
    if( confirm( "Sure?" ) ) {
        return handleOnClickConfirmed.call( this );
    }
    return false;
}
```

The [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function attached to `Function` objects is designed to allow this; calling a function with a desired context. It's an extremely useful trick when setting up event handlers that call back into functions within other objects.

Comment: Many thanks.  =]  I was thinking of some kind of this.call(fn), but I guess I got the order switched around.

Answer (score 11):

Rob's answer is the best answer for your problem, but I wanted to address something that you wrote in your original question:

> I know I can pass this as an argument to handleOnClickConfirmed, but some of my code already uses handleOnClickConfirmed and I don't want to have to rewrite those calls.

JavaScript parameters are always optional, as far as the interpreter is concerned.  For example if you have the function:

```
function MyFunction(paramA, paraB) {
  // do nothing
}
```

All of these calls will execute without error:

```
MyFunction(1,2);
MyFunction(1);
MyFunction();
```

So you could modify handleOnClickConfirmed to accept what would essentially be an optional parameter.  Like so:

```
function handleOnClickConfirmed(context) {
  context = context || this;
  // use context instead of 'this' through the rest of your code
}
```

Again, in this particular case, the call function is the best solution.  But the technique I outlined above is a good one to have in your toolbox.