# Why is this wrong? (use of "this" with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function bigtosmalltriangle() {
            $(this).siblings("div.break").removeClass('triangle3').addClass('triangle1');
            setTimeout ( "smalltomediumtriangle()", 400 );
        }
        function smalltomediumtriangle() {
            $(this).siblings("div.break").removeClass('triangle1').addClass('triangle2');
            setTimeout ( "mediumtobigtriangle()", 400 );
        }
        function mediumtobigtriangle() {
            $(this).siblings("div.break").removeClass('triangle2').addClass('triangle3');
            setTimeout ( "bigtosmalltriangle()", 400 );
        }

    $(function() {
        $("span#clickhere").click(
            function() {
                /* do a lot stuff here */ bigtosmalltriangle();
                $(this).hide();
            }
        );
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .triangle1 {background:#000;}
    .triangle2 {background:red;}
    .triangle3 {background:white;}
</style>
```

```
<div><div class="break">Hello World</div><span id="clickhere">asdf</span></div>
```

I'm trying to get get the div.break to scroll through 3 bgcolors, but when I click on the span it has no effect. Does anyone know what I should do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "this" is not bound to the span you clicked on in the bigtosmalltriangle, smalltomediumtriangle, and mediumtobigtriangle functions. You need to either pass in the element as a parameter, or set a variable that's in scope in all the functions through closures.

### Parameter passing:

```
function bigtosmalltriangle(elements) {
    elements.removeClass('triangle3').addClass('triangle1');
    setTimeout(function() { smalltomediumtriangle(elements); }, 400);
}
function smalltomediumtriangle(elements) {
    elements.removeClass('triangle1').addClass('triangle2');
    setTimeout(function() { mediumtobigtriangle(elements); }, 400);
}
function mediumtobigtriangle(elements) {
    elements.removeClass('triangle2').addClass('triangle3');
    setTimeout(function() { bigtosmalltriangle(elements); }, 400);
}

$(function() {
    $("span#clickhere").click(
        function() {
            /* do a lot stuff here */
            bigtosmalltriangle($(this).siblings("div.break"));
            $(this).hide();
        }
    );
});
```

### Closures:

```
$(function() {
    $("span#clickhere").click(
        function() {
            var elements = $(this).siblings("div.break");

            function bigtosmalltriangle() {
                elements.removeClass('triangle3').addClass('triangle1');
                setTimeout(smalltomediumtriangle, 400);
            }
            function smalltomediumtriangle() {
                elements.removeClass('triangle1').addClass('triangle2');
                setTimeout(mediumtobigtriangle, 400);
            }
            function mediumtobigtriangle() {
                elements.removeClass('triangle2').addClass('triangle3');
                setTimeout(bigtosmalltriangle, 400);
            }

            /* do a lot stuff here */
            bigtosmalltriangle();
            $(this).hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: it's a very messy way to do it - strager's answer is the better response.

Answer (score 3):

You want to call your functions with a specific "this".  I asked a similar question: [Call function with "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325004/call-function-with-this).

```
$(function() {
        $("span#clickhere").click(
                function() {
                        /* do a lot stuff here */
                        bigtosmalltriangle.call(this);
                        $(this).hide();
                }
        );
});
```

I think because of closures (see Matthew Crumley's answer) the callback functions themselves don't need to be modified, because setTimeout keeps the "scope."  I don't know Javascript enough to remotely guarantee that, though.  If I am wrong, simply perform the `.call(this)` trick for the callback functions as well.

Comment: The callback functions would need to be modified, because when setTimeout calls them, "this" will refer to the global scope (i.e. window). I don't see an advantage to using "this" instead of passing the elements as a parameter.