# How, using JavaScript, do I change an <a> tag's onclick event handler to a function with parameters?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm aware that you can set an `onclick` handler like this:

```
my_a = document.createElement('a');
my_a.onclick = somefunction;
```

... but what if `somefunction` takes a parameter? For the sake of simplicity, let's say I need to pass it the string `"x"`. Is it possible to dynamically set the `onclick` handler to `somefunction('x')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you would create an anonymous function:

```
my_a = document.createElement('a');
my_a.onclick = function() { somefunction(x); };
```

If you also like to refer to `this` in `somefunction`, you could use a library like [Prototype][1], then you would do something like:

```
my_a = document.createElement('a');
my_a.onclick = somefunction.bind(this, x);
```

[1]: http://alternateidea.com/blog/articles/2007/7/18/javascript-scope-and-binding Blog article

Answer (score 2):

You want to use what is called an **anonymous function**:

```
my_a.onclick = function() {
    somefunction(arguments, here);
};
```

If you want to retain "this" you can [utilize closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325004/call-function-with-this):

```
my_a.onclick = function() {
    somefunction.call(my_a, arguments, here);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a *partial function application*:

```
function partial(func /*, 0..n args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(1);
  return function() {
    var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    return func.apply(this, allArguments);
  };
}
```

Now, you will be able to do this:

```
my_a.onclick = partial(somefunction,1,2,3); //1,2,3 being some parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to wrap it in an anonymous function. Like this:

```
my_a.onclick = function() { somefunction('x'); };
```

The downside is that `this` will no longer refer to `my_a` inside of the `someFunction` function, but if you don't need it to, then the anonymous function should work.