# I need help with the $(this) context in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need some help in this code block:

```
options.imgs.click(function() {
            var allImgs = $("#big img");
            $("#big img").each(function(n) {
                this.index = n;
            })
            animateImage(allImgs);
        })

    };

    function animateImage(images) {
        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            if (images[i].index == 0) {
                alert($(this).index)
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is:

```
$(this).effect('scale', { percent: 200 }, 1000)
```

Isn't working. I want that statement to refer to the image with the index of 0, and scale it 200%. But `$(this)` isn't referring to the first image at all.

Comment: I don't see where you are using the problem code in your example. but you can always do $("#big img:first").effect to apply the animation to the first img

Comment: @Deviant, The problem line he pastes likely belongs in the animateImage function.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you call your function your "*this*" variable is changed:

```
function test() {
  alert(this); // this will be the window object
}
$('p b').click(function() {
   alert(this); // this will be the bold element object
   test();
});
```

For example, running this against this page (using firebug), I can click on the "asked" and "viewed" items on the right at the top (they are bolded)... And what you get back is an alert from the test function where *this* is the window object, **not** the bold element as it is in the event handler.

To fix this, just pass the object you would like to work on through the function:

```
options.imgs.click(function() {
            var allImgs = $("#big img");
            $("#big img").each(function(n) {
                    this.index = n;
            })
            animateImage(allImgs, this);
    })

};

function animateImage(images, img) {
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            if (images[i].index == 0) {
                    alert($(img).index)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Call function with “this”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325004/call-function-with-this).

Basically what you want is to replace

```
animateImage(allImgs);
```

with

```
animateImage.call(this, allImgs);
```

---

You can refactor your code into this (or something similar):

```
options.imgs.click(function() {
    var allImgs = $("#big img");
    allImgs.each(function(n) {
        this.index = n;
    });

    allImgs.get(0).effect('scale', { percent: 200 }, 1000);
});
```

You can also begin the effect inside the `each` argument where `n == 0`.  (I didn't do this in my example because it's not exactly like the code you have (ignoring ugly concurrency issues)).

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside the call to click, the first parameter ("this") is the DOM element you clicked. Does your DOM element have a "index" property?

I also recommend you to use a "object dump" function (an example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/skillet/archive/2006/03/23/440940.aspx ). The usage is similar to this:

```
$("a").click( function(){ 
   alert( object_dump( this ) ) 
});
```

(note that the object_dump() function returns a string, you need to "alert()" it or do something else with it).